# How to manipulate a list bean defined in XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring, list

I have an XML Spring configuration containing a list

```
<util:list id="deviceList" value-type="package.path.to.Device">
    <ref bean="device1"/>
    <ref bean="device2"/>
</util:list>
```

that is being autowired into my Java code:

```
@Autowired
private List<Device> devices;
```

As I am working on a dynamic web project, it is possible to add and delete devices to/from the list at runtime.

I have a thread that triggers sensors on the devices periodically and that gets the initial device list by constructor injection:

```
<bean id="sensorTriggerThread" scope="singleton" class="package.path.to.SensorTriggerThread">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="deviceList"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I can add and delete new devices normally with the devices.add / devices.remove method, but that does not influence the list in the XML file, which results in the newly created devices not getting triggered. I am fairly new to Spring and it seems I found that autowiring does not work in both directions.
How can I manipulate the device list from the XML file in a Java class?
I know that it is possible to somehow edit this list as a bean so that all parts of the application that relate to it also get these changes.

**EDIT**: I should mention I have no write access to the SensorTriggerThread file as it is part of a jar library.

Comment: Seems `SensorTriggerThread` does not use reference for your list, but copy `devuceList` items into internal list. That's why any changes of `deviceList` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the @Autowired annotation to an @Resource(name="deviceList") annotation. Not sure why this was necessary as I only have 1 list of devices configured in the XML file but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a thread that triggers the devices periodically and that gets
>   the *initial device list* by constructor injection.

You can always set the new device list through a setter method in `sensorTriggerThread`.

Comment: That would work but the SensorTriggerThread is not my source file but part of a jar library. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.